# Why can I fill my black star by soul trapping a mammoth?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have tested this twice, both times I had no empty grand soul gems and I had an empty black star. I soul trapped a mammoth and killed it and my black star got filled with a grand soul. I thought the black star was only for black souls!

I know mammoths do not have black souls as their souls normally fill into empty grand soul gems. Think this is some sort of a glitch or bug, has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: If you want to fix this bug on the PC, get the **[Acquisitive Soul Gems](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/5312)** mod.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the UESP wiki, [the Black Star](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star_%28item%29#The_Black_Star) should only get filled with black (i.e. humanoid) souls, but due to a bug/glitch (as you said) it also accepts 'white' (i.e. non-humanoid) souls.

Comment: does that mean I can fill any soul in my black star?

Comment: Yes, at least until the bug gets fixed :)

Comment: The Unofficial Skyrim Patch does indeed fix this now.